# use pop3 transport protocol yii2 swiftmailer

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer, pop3

I want to send email from my application, but my host want extra money for smtp protocol
Is there a way to send email by `swiftmailer` in yii2 wit pop3 protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending email via Yii2 You can follow the below procedure.

**main.php**

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',


            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
             //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
            'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'email id',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],

            ],
```

**Controller**

```
\Yii::$app->mail->compose('your_view', ['params' => $params])
    ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => 'Test Mail'])
    ->setTo('to_email@xyz.com')
    ->setSubject('This is a test mail ' )
    ->send();
```

For more details please refer
[Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html)

Answer (score -1):

The pop3 protocol is only for getting mail from server is not for send mail !

But for sending mail you can use the default php mail function

You can read more on the following :

[function.mail.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)